# Copy a word from a function to a string with strcpy in C?

Tags: c, string, strcpy

I'm in a basic C programming course and I'm trying to create a hangman game. I've been stuck with a problem for the last three hours and I'm not getting any wiser.

Basically, I've created a function which reads a random line from a text file and then copies it to a string. Afterwards, I want to copy that string to another string outside off the function. This is because the main game is supposed to be completely built with functions.

This is the function that reads a random word from the text file and copies it to a string:

```
char datorns_val()
{
  char ordlista[20];
  char valt_ord[20];
  int raknare = 0;


  srand(time(NULL));
  random = rand()%10+0;          

  ptr_file =fopen("hangman.txt","r");
  if (!ptr_file)
  {
    return 1;
  }

  while (fgets(ordlista,20, ptr_file)!=NULL)
  {
    raknare++;
    if (raknare == random)
      strcpy(valt_ord, ordlista);
  }

  return valt_ord;
}
```

After this is done, I want to copy the word located in valt_ord to another string, and that's when I'm unsure about what to do:

```
char word[20];
strcpy(word,datorns_val());
```

I'm getting two errors that says:

`Invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'`

and

`initializing argument 2 of 'char* strcpy(char*, const char*)'`

Am I on the right track here with using `strcpy()` twice or am I completely lost? I tried my build without a function structure and simply typing out all the code on after another and it works, if a replace the second `strcpy()` with a simple `char word = valt_ord.`

Thanks, Jonathan

(Sorry if my code is hard to understand, I'm swedish and my second language is English)

Comment: You are returning an char array that is on the stack, so this won't work. You need to return a copy of it on the heap, that you allocate with `malloc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you're returning a character, which is not of much use, since you need a string that will outlive the function which creates it. You should return a dynamically allocated string (using a pointer) for this.

```
 char* datorns_val()
 {
      // ... your current code
      char *ret_str = malloc(20);
      strcpy(ret_str, valt_ord);
      return ret_str;
 }
```

At the end where you use it, you should free it when done.

```
 char *result = datorns_val();
 // use result
 free(result);
 result = NULL;
```

Alternatively, if you're sure that the function which is calling the `datorns_val` is the only one which is going to use the result, then I'd recommend something else which doesn't involve dynamic memory alloc/decalloc (`malloc`/`free`). Pass the string to be loaded to `datorns_val`.

```
int datorns_val(char (*str_ptr)[20])   // pointer to an array of 20 chars
{
    // use str_ptr after dereferencing it to get back the char array
    // say you want to copy "abc" to it
    strcpy(*str_ptr, "abc");
    return 0;    // to denote success, you may return -1 for failure
}

// caller's end
char result[20] = "";
int success = datorns_val(&result);   // pass the array by reference
```

Read more about [arrays and pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) to know more about them.

Comment: Thank you legends, this solved the problem!

I don't think dynamic memory allocation is necessary, since we haven't gotten to that part in the course yet. I do think I need to read up on pointers and arrays since the mistake I made feels a bit stupid.

Comment: Welcome! Arrays and pointers are stumbling blocks when learning _C_. It becomes better when you read [the right books](http://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/183120) and practise a lot. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Your function `datorns_val` is declared to return `char` while in fact it returns `valt_ord` that is of type `char[]`. Also there is a way bigger problem `valt_ord` is a local variable so even if you change the declaration the code will not work. You will need to allocate `valt_ord` dynamically(using `malloc`) or to pass it as function argument.

Comment: You had to say "pass its adress as function argument" else it also wouldn't work.

Comment: @Zaibis It depends on what the author wants to do. My idea is to modify the array in the function, not allocate it and avoid using dynamic memory in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

argument 2 of `strcpy` needed string but your function returning char.

[man strcpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy).

you trying to return local variable, it will be destroyed when you move out of function because it stores the data in `stack`. Use `malloc`

[see this SO question for further clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)